# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS i want to upgrade all packages

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, update-manager

sudo apt upgrade and sudo apt full-upgrade doesn't work,the following 8 packages won't upgrade:

```
gnome-initial-setup/jammy-updates 42.0.1-1ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.0.1-1ubuntu2]
gnome-remote-desktop/jammy-updates 42.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.3-0ubuntu1]
python3-software-properties/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.2]
software-properties-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.2]
software-properties-gtk/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.2]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy-updates 27.13.3~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 27.9~22.04.1]
update-notifier-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 3.192.54.5 all [upgradable from: 3.192.54]
update-notifier/jammy-updates 3.192.54.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.192.54]
```

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that their is a reason these updates have been held back, either due to your apt settings, or they could conflict with another package.  To fix it, just run `apt install <package name>`

if you want to install all of them in one command run:

```
apt full-upgrade | awk -F / ' {system("apt install "$1)}'
```

if you are not in a root shell, you will need to add sudo to both commands

```
sudo apt full-upgrade | awk -F / ' {system("sudo apt install "$1)}'
```

*** sudo or running apt in a root shell is assumed

Comment: it denied permission

Comment: If you are not in a root shell, you need to add sudo in front of the command.  any command that is located in sbin, or other system directories but be ran form a root shell, or with sudo.

Comment: it denied even when i put in sudo in front of it and it asked if i was root instead of in root

Comment: That is strange it is only a few packages so just run :

sudo apt install gnome-initial-setup gnome-remote-desktop python3-software-properties software-properties-common software-properties-gtk ubuntu-advantage-tools update-notifier-common update-notifier

That will install the latest version of each of the packages.

Comment: that worked,thanks a lot